# ClassNotFoundException for HibernatePersistenceProvider

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, jboss

I have a JSF project which builds perfectly with java 7, but when I try to deploy the WAR in Jboss Application Server, I'm getting the bellow error.

```
00:24:30,940 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-16) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war".INSTALL: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:119) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: JBAS011426: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:91)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider from [Module "deployment.sample-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderProcessor.deploy(PersistenceProviderProcessor.java:76)
    ... 6 more
```

The `persistance.xml` looks like bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="com.inmatic_JMS_war_1.0-SNAPSHOTPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>MySQLDS</jta-data-source>
      <class>com.rnavagamuwa.paypal.business.entity.PayPalPayment</class>
      <class>com.rnavagamuwa.catalogue.stock.business.entity.MaterialStockOrder</class>
      <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

The bellow dependencies are included in the pom

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.21.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
```

The JBoss version is *7.1.1 Final*

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: JBoss provides the JPA implementation without giving you direct access to the implementation. You can remove the `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` from persistence.xml. If you want an alternative provider (e.g. another version of Hibernate) you have to bundle it with your application, i.e. drop `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>`. By the way, make sure you are not bundling the javaee & JPA APIs with your application!

Comment: I have removed `<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>` from the `persistence.xml` and removed the `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `hibernate-entitymanager`  but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here was the conflict between the Hibernate jars in JBoss modules and my project. When I use the JBoss latest one(WildFly 20), the issue went away. Note that I had to copy the MySQL connector jar into WildFly deployments dir and add the following datasource to my project.

```
<datasources xmlns="http://www.jboss.org/ironjacamar/schema">
    <datasource jndi-name="MySQLDS" pool-name="MySQLPool">
        <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db</connection-url>
        <driver>mysql-connector-java-8.0.21.jar</driver>
        <pool>
            <max-pool-size>30</max-pool-size>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>username</user-name>
            <password>password</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
</datasources>
```